# Java - Initiate top panel as invisible

Tags: java, swing

In a card layout I want to start with the first card invisible. Since it has some transparency, this is intended to make sure it stays on top when called, sice other panels will be visible as well. I tried to initiate it with .setVisible(false) but it isn't working, since as my program starts, it is shown with no transparency and with no other panel visible. Does the visibility of a panel is not setup the same way as its components? How can this be done?

Relevant piece of code:

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

    addStoreHelpPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());
    addStoreHelpPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    addStoreHelpPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    addStoreHelpPanel.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: code is not enough to say something.Where your addStoreHelpPanel added to the layout?

Comment: @Serkhan every component on the panel is added and then the panel is added to the layout

Comment: You simply need to add an empty panel (or label) as first component in your card layout holder. Don't make your `addStoreHelpPanel` invisible.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I tried to, but if I add an empty panel, the empty panel will be the first thing to appear, not the landing page. I just get a gray panel